# FolderBrowserDialog and OpenFileDialog when selecting a file or folder in a long path

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a question about FolderBrowserDialog and OpenFileDialog in C#.net when selecting a file or folder in a long path if you know any method to use it in the long path??

always FolderBrowserDialog return this message "The folder \\?\C:\Test\Roooooooooooooooot\New Folder\Main...\New...\New Folder..." can't be used. Please choose another folder.

Comment: Is the '\?' at the start a paste error? If not that is likely the problem.

Comment: @Slugsie DOS Device Paths: [Path Format Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/path-format-overview) -- [.NET 4.6.2 and long paths on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10)

Comment: It seams you are missing a \ in your path prefix? `\\?\...`

Comment: sorry, this is the right path returned in the message "\\?\C:\Test\Roooooooooooooooot\New Folder\Main...\New...\New Folder..."

Comment: Please include a [mre]. Also, is that the *exact* path you're trying to access ellipses ('...') and all, or are you truncating it for brevity? I just tried creating the path as given with ellipses and Windows Explorer won't allow such folder names. If it isn't the *exact* path, please provide it as part of the [mre].